# How to use user input using CLIPS

Tags: clips

I am a beginner in CLIPS and cannot figure out how to get the above code to work right despite spending hours on it. Any help would be appreciated.Thank you.

```
(deftemplate gem
(players <number_robots>)
(Goal_posts <number_goal_posts>)
(Field <dimension>)
(players goalkeeper <number_goalkeepers> <goalkeeper_linear_speed> <goalkeeper_angular_speed> {static, running})
(players defenders <number_defenders> <defender_linear_speed> <defender_angular_speed> {static, running})
(players midfielder <number_midfielders> <midfielder_linear_speed> <midfielder_angular_speed> {static, running})
(players striker <number_strikers> <striker_linear_speed> <striker_angular_speed> {static, running})
(ball <poz_x> <poz_y)
(oponents <nume> <poz_oponents_x> <poz_oponents_y>))

(deffacts initial-state
    (player goalkeeper 1 10 6 static)
    (player defenders number_defenders 15 10 running)
    (player midfielders number_midfielders 17 12 running)
    (player strikers number_strikers 9 10 running)
    (ball 5 5)
    (oponents Robot1 1 2)
    (oponents Robot2 2 4)
    (oponents Robot3 7 2)
    (oponents Robot4 10 20)
    (oponents Robot5 11 8)
    (oponents Robot6 20 10)
    (oponents Robot7 5 9)
)

;The number of robots per team must be variable and the user has to be able to set or adjust it.
(defrule number_of_robots
    =>    
    (printout t "Type the number of robots per team"               
        crlf)    
        (assert (number_robots (read))) 
    (printout t "Type the number of goal posts" crlf)    
        (assert (number_goal_posts (read))))
(defrule check-input   
    ?number_robots <-        
        (number ?number_robots)  
        (test (integerp ?number_robots))
        =>    
        (retract ?number_robots)    
        (printout t "Correct number of robots" crlf))
(defrule check-input1       
    ?number_goal_posts <-  
        (number ?number_goal_posts)  
        (test (integerp ?number_goal_posts))
        =>    
        (retract ?number_goal_posts)    
        (printout t "Correct number of goal posts" crlf))
                
;The user will initially input data on the dimension of the fotball field and goal post.
(defrule dimension_field 
    =>    
    (printout t "Type the football field dimension" crlf)    
        (assert (dimension (read)))) 
(defrule check-input1    
    ?dimension <- 
        (number ?dimension)  
        (test (integerp ?dimension))
        =>    
        (retract ?dimension)    
        (printout t "Correct dimension of footbal field" crlf))
        
;Each team must have a goalkeeper, while the number of defenders, midfielders and strikers is to be set by the user to match the stated number of players
(defrule reading-input
    =>
    printout t "Type the number of defenders" crlf   
        (assert (number_defenders(read)))
    printout t "Type the number of midfielders" crlf  
        (assert (number_midfielders(read)))
    printout t "Type the number of strikers" crlf 
        (assert (number_strikers(read)))
)
         
(defrule check-input2       
    ?number_defenders <- 
        (number ?number_defenders)  
        (test (integerp ?number_defenders))
        =>    
        (retract ?number_defenders)    
        (printout t "Correct number of defenders " crlf))
        
(defrule check-input3   
    ?number_midfielders <-    
        (number ?number_midfielders)  
        (test (integerp ?number_midfielders))
        =>    
        (retract ?number_midfielders)    
        (printout t "Correct number of midfielders " crlf))
(defrule check-input4   
    ?number_strikers <- 
        (number ?number_strikers)  
        (test (integerp ?number_strikers))
        =>    
        (retract ?number_strikers)    
        (printout t "Correct number of strikers " crlf))
)
```

My errors after running the code are:

> [PRNTUTIL2] Syntax Error:  Check appropriate syntax for deftemplate.
>
> ERROR:
> (deftemplate MAIN::gem
> (players
>
> [CSTRCPSR1] WARNING: Redefining deffacts: initial-state
>
> [CSTRCPSR1] WARNING: Redefining defrule: number_of_robots +j Defining
> defrule: check-input =j+j
>
> [CSTRCPSR1] WARNING: Redefining defrule: check-input1 =j+j
>
> [CSTRCPSR1] WARNING: Redefining defrule: dimension_field +j
>
> [CSTRCPSR1] WARNING: Redefining defrule: check-input1 =j+j
>
> [CSTRCPSR1] WARNING: Redefining defrule: reading-input +j
>
> [CSTRCPSR1] WARNING: Redefining defrule: check-input2 =j+j
>
> [CSTRCPSR1] WARNING: Redefining defrule: check-input3 =j+j
>
> [CSTRCPSR1] WARNING: Redefining defrule: check-input4 =j+j
>
> [CSTRCPSR1] Expected the beginning of a construct.

Answer (score 0):

```
CLIPS> 
(defrule number_of_robots
   =>    
   (printout t "Type the number of robots per team: ")    
   (assert (number_robots (read))) 
   (printout t "Type the number of goal posts: ")    
   (assert (number_goal_posts (read))))
CLIPS> 
(defrule check-robots   
   ?number <- (number_robots ?number_robots)  
   (test (not (integerp ?number_robots)))
   =>    
   (retract ?number)    
   (printout t "Correct number of robots." crlf))
CLIPS> 
(defrule check-goal-posts       
    ?number <- (number_goal_posts ?number_goal_posts)  
    (test (not (integerp ?number_goal_posts)))
    =>    
    (retract ?number)    
    (printout t "Correct number of goal posts." crlf))
CLIPS>                 
(defrule dimension_field 
   =>    
   (printout t "Type the football field dimension: ")    
   (assert (dimension (read)))) 
CLIPS> 
(defrule check-dimension    
    ?dim <- (dimension ?dimension)  
    (test (not (integerp ?dimension)))
    =>    
    (retract ?dim)    
    (printout t "Correct dimension of football field." crlf))
CLIPS>         
(defrule reading-input
   =>
   (printout t "Type the number of defenders: ")   
   (assert (number_defenders (read)))
   (printout t "Type the number of midfielders: ")
   (assert (number_midfielders (read)))
   (printout t "Type the number of strikers: ") 
   (assert (number_strikers (read))))
CLIPS>          
(defrule check-defenders       
    ?number <- (number_defenders ?number_defenders)  
    (test (not (integerp ?number_defenders)))
    =>    
    (retract ?number)    
    (printout t "Correct number of defenders." crlf))
CLIPS>         
(defrule check-midfielders   
   ?number <- (number_midfielders ?number_midfielders)  
   (test (not (integerp ?number_midfielders)))
   =>    
   (retract ?number)    
   (printout t "Correct number of midfielders." crlf))
CLIPS>         
(defrule check-strikers   
   ?number <- (number_strikers ?number_strikers)  
   (test (not (integerp ?number_strikers)))
   =>    
   (retract ?number)    
   (printout t "Correct number of strikers." crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Type the number of robots per team: 1
Type the number of goal posts: 2
Type the football field dimension: 3
Type the number of defenders: 4
Type the number of midfielders: 5
Type the number of strikers: 6
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Type the number of robots per team: a
Type the number of goal posts: b
Correct number of goal posts.
Correct number of robots.
Type the football field dimension: c
Correct dimension of football field.
Type the number of defenders: d
Type the number of midfielders: e
Type the number of strikers: f
Correct number of strikers.
Correct number of midfielders.
Correct number of defenders.
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Gary! I still have 2 tasks on this matter that I don't know how to implement.... maybe you could help me?                                                                                        1) The goalkeeper has to move on the goal post line in that position where it can block
the trajectory of the ball.
2) The defenders have to move so that to block the ball in its trajectory towards goal or
to block the trajectory of an opponent player that moves towards the goal post that
must be defended.